# PHP - Are translations in controllers always bad?

Tags: php, design-patterns, translation, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2, but this question is not really ZF2 specific.

I have a situation where it would be convenient for me to translate a string in my controller rather than in my view script. Generally, I translate in the view scripts, but in a few scenarios, it is not so convenient. I feel as if it is definitely not the controller's job to do this, but I would like to hear opinions about this as well as recommendations.

To show what I mean, here is a scenario where it would be convenient:

```
public function registerAction() {
    try {
        $service_layer->registerUser(...);
    }

    catch (\My\Specific\Exception $e) {
        $error = $this->translate('Something specific went wrong');
    }

    catch (\Exception $e) {
        $error = $this->translate('Unfortunately, an error occurred!');
    }

    return array('error' => $error); // Pass error to view
}
```

I know how I can translate in the controller, so that is not a worry. Here I make use of a service layer, which may potentially throw exceptions. I would like to catch these so I can present the user with a helpful error message. Because several different errors can occur, I cannot simply send a boolean value to the view indicating if an error occurred, because then I cannot distinguish between which error happened.

So, I could translate the strings in the controller and print out the variables in my view script. This would make things easy when I use poedit to find translation strings. Alternatively, I could just return the non-translated strings and do `$this->translate($error);` in the view script. With this approach, I have a problem with detecting translation strings in my controllers. Using PHP's `gettext()` method just for this purpose seems like a waste of resources just so I can find the strings automatically.

I would like to hear what you guys think I should do in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: btw, this question should be on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ not here...

Comment: @DaniloKobold Correct, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the correct approach is to have the exception throwing an error code that should be translated within the view context.

I agree with you that this would be a wate of ressource but at the other hand it would make the application more reliable and modular which is the sole propose of using this approach, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Always throw the error message. If someone really needs error messages translated, then they can do so on their own. The primary language for `Exception`s though should always be english.

And then if someone needs to translate the `Exception` they can do so from the view-scripts:

```
echo $this->translate($e->getMessage());
```

Comment: +1. To clarify, Exceptions should not be used for intended control flow, as they are literally meant as *exceptions*. Something like a failed form validation or a user name that already exists ideally should not result in an exception thrown by your service layer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should just write exception messages within my service layer, for instance, without worrying about translation. Then if they really need to be translated, I can do it within the view? I have two questions about this; firstly, wouldn't I then need to manually find these translation strings for my translation file? Secondly, should I simply pass the error message to the view as a string, or is there a way in which I can throw the exceptions and catch them in the view? I am unsure about the latter, because throwing an exception means my view model is not returned.